# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError at /auth/facebook/callback with omniauth

Tags: ruby, openssl, sinatra, omniauth

I'm dealing with the OpenSLL error on windows, using omniauth.
I've tried specifying the cacert.pem file. It is placed in my_app_dir\assets\cacert.pem (downloaded from the curl website), and

```
provider :facebook, APP_ID, SECRET, {:client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => File.dirname(__FILE__) << "assets\cacert.pem"}}}
```

does not work. I still get the OpenSSL Error. I decided that I don't need my windows machine to verify as I will be deploying to a linux server anyway, so for now I wanted to set it to not verify at all:

```
SCOPE = 'email,read_stream'

APP_ID = "2XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
SECRET = "4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, APP_ID, SECRET, {:client_options => {:ssl => {:verify => false}}}
end
```

I still get the error.
At this point, I don't really care whether or not it uses a certificate (I would prefer it do), I need to get it to work so that I can get past this roadblock.

The specific error says:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following the instructions given in this link:
http://jimneath.org/2011/10/19/ruby-ssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

And you have to make this minor change in `fix_ssl.rb` at the end:

```
self.ca_file = Rails.root.join('lib/ca-bundle.crt').to_s
```

I hope this helps.